# useEffect causing infinite loop with data population from DB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks

I am passing data from a db load query into my script, and having a useEffect to update the existing data.
This is for some reason causing the UE to run infinitely.
useEffect as follow, with it called by the array of data that comes from the DB.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("UE1"); // running on infinite loop. TODO: DEBUG. 
    setCircles(paramsObject?.circles)
}, [paramsObject])
```

Updating this useState with circle elements (svg):

```js
//ocircles created/creating
const [circles, setCircles] = useState([]);
```

I am unsure what to try as this useEffect is essential to loading data and using it as the current data state for the page.

Here is more code for context:

```
//CIRCLES ARRAY const [circles, setCircles] = useState([]);  
const { id } = useParams(); 
const { data } = useQuery(LOAD_DATA);   
const loadedData = data?.params.find(element => id === element._id); const loadedID = loadedData?._id; 
const paramsObject = JSON.parse(loadedData?.params || '{}');

useEffect(()=>{         
setCircles(paramsObject?.circles) 
},[paramsObject]
```

Comment: How is `paramsObject` defined? It looks like it's changing every render

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. So it's changing when data is loaded in from the DB. Here is the full code if that helps?

Comment: paramsObject is defined through the loading of data through the LOAD_DATA query. 

It is an object containing an array 'params' of svg circle elements. 

I'm trying to work out if I should add another hook to the useEffect call, but unsure. 

I am very new to react after learning JS for two years first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const loadedData = data?.params.find(element => id === element._id);
```

The search result is recalculated after each rerender, a new array reference is created because of this, each time a new reference to the paramsObject is obtained.

In total it turns out that you do setState in useEffect and start the rerender process, the reference to the variables mentioned above changes, useEffect works again and so on in a circle

You can wrap everything in useMemo but that's not the best solution.
I can't see all your code, so I can't write a ready-made solution, but I can advise you to rewrite useEffect so that it only updates when the id changes

Comment: Thank you this has led me to the solution.!

Comment: The issue is JSON.parse, not the result of .find()

Comment: @AndyRay please justify your answer

Answer (score -1):

I have worked the simple solution.. it may be a bandaid..

But, i simply changed the useEffect call to be:

`[array.length]` rather than `[array]`